# Why can't I cross compile?

Tags: visual-studio, cross-platform, cocos2d-x-3.0

I use [Cocos2d](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocos2d) 3.16 (`cocos2d-x-3.16` and Visual Studio 2015.

I developed a game in Visual Studio 2015. I want to transplant it to the phone to play, but I found that the cross compilation could not complete! I've tried the solution I know, like modifying file *android.mk*, but it's still not resolved.

In desperation, I created a new project, but it did nothing. I cross compiled directly, but it did not work. I was frustrated. I remember clearly, just last week it was all good, because we had been cross compiling a couple APKs. Why is it not okay today?

Error message:

[image: Error]

Comment: Related: *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)*. It includes (my emphasis) *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way***, *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been solved with the help of the domestic compatriots. The reason is simple: There is an invalid character "-" in the file of "AndroidManifest.xml". As stated in the question, the red box (originally, because I don't understand the English reason) I only use browser search to translate the contents of the red box, but not translation from the nearest word! It is my laziness and negligence. I deserved it!